# Control Graphviz arrows direction

Tags: graphviz

I'm tying to draw the [IDEF0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF0#/media/File:IDEF_Top-Level_Context_Diagram.jpg) diagram example using Graphviz [image]

```
digraph UDEF0 {
 "Plan New Information Program" [shape=box]
 "Issues"                       [shape=none]
 "Operation Data"               [shape=none]
 "Program Charter"              [shape=none]
 "Program Team"                 [shape=none]
 "Program Plan"                 [shape=none]

 "Issues" ->            "Plan New Information Program"
 "Operation Data" ->    "Plan New Information Program"

 "Program Charter" ->   "Plan New Information Program"

 "Program Team" ->      "Plan New Information Program"

 "Plan New Information Program" -> "Program Plan" 
}
```

The problem is that I can't find the way to control direction of arrows around the central box.

I've tried to use hidden "frame" made of invisible South, North, East  and West nodes to connect arrows to them. Unfortunately the "frame" works well only if it is empty, and when I connect my "payload" nodes to it, the structure breaks:

```
digraph UDEF0 {
   rankdir=LR
   "Plan New Information Program" [shape=box]
   "Issues"                       [shape=none]
   "Operation Data"               [shape=none]
   "Program Charter"              [shape=none]
   "Program Team"                 [shape=none]
   "Program Plan"                 [shape=none]
   "Program Plan"                 [shape=none]


   "West"                 [shape=none]
   "North"                 [shape=none]
   "South"                 [shape=none]
   "East"                 [shape=none]
   "West" -> "North" -> "East"
   "West" -> "South" -> "East"


   "West" -> "Issues" ->            "Plan New Information Program"
   "West" -> "Operation Data" ->    "Plan New Information Program"

   "North" -> "Program Charter" ->   "Plan New Information Program"

   "South" -> "Program Team" ->      "Plan New Information Program"

   "East" -> "Plan New Information Program" -> "Program Plan"
}
```

Is the any correct way to implement this diagram style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `shape = record` brings you close to what you want - here my re-written attempt:

```
digraph UDEF0
{
    A[ label = "Plan New\nInformation\nProgram", shape=box, style = filled, fillcolor = grey ]
    B[ shape = record, color = white, label = "{ Operation Data | Issues }" ]
    node[ shape = none ]
    c[ label = "Program Charter" ]
    d[ label = "Program Team" ]
    e[ label = "Program Plan" ] 

    { rank = same; A B e }

    c -> A;
    A -> d[ dir = back ];
    edge[ minlen = 3]
    B -> A;
    B -> A;
    A -> e;
}
```

yields

[image]

**E D I T  2018-11-29**

In order to avoid the issues that @McKay has shown in his comment, I have re-coded the sample using a HTML like label:

```
digraph UDEF0
{
    A[ label = "Plan New\nInformation\nProgram", shape=box, style = filled, fillcolor = grey ]

    B[ shape = plaintext, label =<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="15">
        <TR>
            <TD PORT = "p1">Issues</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD PORT = "p2">Operation Data</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>>];

    node[ shape = none ]
    c[ label = "Program Charter" ]
    d[ label = "Program Team" ]
    e[ label = "Program Plan" ] 

    { rank = same; A B e }

    c -> A;
    A -> d[ dir = back ];
    edge[ minlen = 3]
    B:p1 -> A;
    B:p2 -> A;
    A -> e;
}
```

Which gives us

[image]

without warning or error message on my Linux box with `graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)`.

Comment: When I paste your code as is, I get `Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
  Edge B -> A
Error: lost B A edge
Error: lost B A edge`

Comment: Can't check right now, @McKay, but maybe a matter of graphviz version. Anyway, I will re-write with HTML but it'll take a few days.

Comment: See edits, @McKay. By the way, on my box the old version still compiles without warning or error but HTML like labels are more "future proof" it seems.

Comment: Is it just me or does "dir=back" feel ugly to anyone else? You draw the arrow one way in code, but then you tell it to go back the other way.

Comment: `A` is higher up in the hierarchy, so you want your edge to point top down, even though the arrow points in the other direction. Just try out what happens when you write `d -> A`!

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just the rendering engine of dot I don't like. I'm going to be looking into FDP.